# Embedded a PHP code in jQuery in Option tag

Tags: php, jquery

Dynamically generate a drop down on click of button and when a drop down create in that display a data of product from product table in option tag. So how do I embedded PHP code in option tag in jQuery?

This is my code for generating a dropdown:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.my-form .add-box').click(function () {
        var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
        var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"><label>Product:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><select name="boxes[]" value="" id="box' + n + '" style="width:450px; height:40px;"><option>Select Product</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="remove-box btn btn-danger">Delete</a><br><br></p>');
        box_html.hide();
        $('.my-form p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
        box_html.fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
    $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function () {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).remove();
            $('.box-number').each(function (index) {
                $(this).text(index + 1);
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Already I done this:

```
<div class="my-form">
    <p class="text-box">
        <label>Product: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <select id="box1" class="email" name="box[]" style="width:450px; height:40px;">
            <option value="">Select Product</option>
            <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-success addmore add-box"> Add Product </a><br><br>
    </p>
</div>
```

And dropdown also dynamically generated but the problem is in jQuery code in option tag how to apply above php code to display a product name that I don't know

Comment: What PHP code are you trying to embed, and where?

Comment: name of the product i want to display in drop down.

Comment: already one time i create a drop down using this way but when i click on button again create a drop down that is also done but above code i want to embed in jqury that i dont no..

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: It would probably be better to have PHP put the options in the HTML, and hide them with CSS. Then jQuery can just call `.show()` on that element, instead of creating it dynamically.

Comment: No but my criteria is one customer can purchase more than 1 product so i crate a text box dynamically.  can .show() fulfill my criteria?

Comment: Maybe you should clone the `text-box` element and append that.

Comment: Can u give me a code for it

Comment: `var new_box = $(".text-box:first").clone()`. But you'll need to go through all the elements in it that have IDs and change the ID to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Have you got the solution ?